# TVirtualImageList and Form Inheritance in Delphi Rio

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

- I placed TImageCollection on TDataModule and TVirtualImageList on **Form1**.
- Added a couple Images to TImageCollection and linked TVirtualImageList to TImageCollection. All is working perfect.
- Add **Form2** that descends from **Form1**.
- When trying to save new **Form2** I get this message: ***“Cannot assign a TVirtualImageListItem to a TVirtualImageListItem”***.

Comment: Known bug: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-23652

Answer (score 0):

Just double click the TVirtualImageList on Form2, click Clear and OK.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question.